# Interact with iframe - get selected HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

What I really need is a function like the hover-element in Firebug, where we can get the selected HTML.

In our program we will load an URL, and that URL will open in an iFrame. Here we want to hover the elements, and when the user clicks on a certain element, we want the HTML source for that particular element.

So:

- Can you interact (get hovered html) with the iFrame, so you get the selected HTML?

Comment: You cant interact with the iFrame if the content loading is crossdomain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something like you wanted. It will run in a div called sourcecode.

However you can put the sourcecode div in an iframe if you want.

```
<div class="sourceCode">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.outerHTML = function () {
            return $(this).clone().wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
        }
    })(jQuery);

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("p,div").click(function () {

            var thisobject = this;
            var sourcecodes = $(thisobject).outerHTML();
            sourcecodes = htmlEscape(sourcecodes);
            $(".sourceCode").html(sourcecodes);

        });

    });

    function htmlEscape(str) {
        return String(str)
        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Make sure , you have jQuery, because this code will not run without jQuery.
Currently I have included p and div. You can include the whole document.

Comment: I checked for document, and it does not work when you put $(document).click(function
but it will work when you click on a particular div or a p . and the source code will be shown in the div called sourcecode. 

Upvote if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Short version: no.

In practical terms, the only script you can run in an iframe are those scripts in the page loaded in the iframe.

If you want to do something like this, there is a way, but it's nor pretty.
You could use an ajax request to parse the page which would be in an iframe, then load it in your page.
Alternatively, you could write a server side script that recreates the entire iframe page, then you add your interface as an overlay.

None of this is pretty. Blame phishers, scrapers and spammers.